# How to position div's like this with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Trying to maintain an space between them, I'd like to position some divs in a specific form for my website, and then add content to them. I have been styling the pages responsively, so I would like to know if position those divs this way with responsiveness is posible. The result I guess it could be something like this:

[image]

Being X and Y the two div's I've already created (for the header and the menu) and Z the footer. The div's I'd like to put in those positions are those DIV 1, DIV 2 and DIV 3.

For the moment the two main parts above (header and menu) are styled like this:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
    width:90%;
    height:30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:darkblue;
    color:white;
    z-index: 105;
    position:relative;
}

nav {
    width:90%;
    height:22%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:skyblue;
}
```

And the HTML I have for the moment for those DIV 1, DIV 2 and DIV 3 is this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="leftinfo">
        <ul>
            <li>INFO</li>
            <li>ABOUT</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div id="hcontent">
        <div class="tophcontent">

        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="hcontent2">
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've been struggling on how to position it like this, maintaining the web flow with the other divs. Any help or tips about it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean scalable which those divs resize proportionally based on the screen width?

Comment: Yes, and put that DIV1 column and next to it the two horizontal divs of content, with the margins. Thank you.

Comment: Posted you an answer which is fully dynamic and grows/fills the page whether the content is small or big.

Comment: Your answer was great with no doubt but I have quite some problems while trying to add it to my page. Thank you though, I marked you as well.

Comment: @Jim you should know that flex IE8/IE9 doesn't support flex.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with browser compatibility, but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample using `display: flex`. It has today about 94% browser support, which I think one can consider very good.

A great benefit with this, it is fully dynamic regarding the content in each of the elements compared to `float` and `inline-block` versions.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.info, .about, .content-left, .content-right-top,
.content-right-bottom, .footer {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.content-left, .wrapper-inner {
  flex: 1;
}
.wrapper-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.content-right-top, .content-right-bottom {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="info">
    Info<br>
    2 lines
  </div>

  <div class="about">
    About<br>
    in<br>
    3 lines
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-left">
      Left take all the rest of the space
      Left take all the rest of the space
      Left take all the rest of the space
      Left take all the rest of the space
      Left take all the rest of the space
      Left take all the rest of the space
      Left take all the rest of the space
      Left take all the rest of the space
      Left take all the rest of the space
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-inner">
      <div class="content-right-top">
        Right - Top
        Right - Top
        Right - Top
        Right - Top
        Right - Top
        Right - Top
        Right - Top
        Right - Top
      </div>
      <div class="content-right-bottom">
        Right - Bottom
        Right - Bottom
        Right - Bottom
        Right - Bottom
        Right - Bottom
        Right - Bottom
        Right - Bottom
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    Footer<br>
    has 2 lines
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you want something like

https://jsfiddle.net/2dxzr1mv/3/

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
div{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.div1{
  width:20%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:red;
  min-height:100vh;
  display:inline-block;
}
.wrapper{
    width:80%;
    min-height:100vh;
    display:inline-block;
}
.div2,.div3{
  width:100%;
  min-height:50vh;
  background-color:yellow;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space: normal;
}
.div3{
   background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: That's a good answer, thank you. However, in the DIV2 my lorem provisional text gets out of the div. How to correct that?

Comment: use word-wrap: break-word in your div2

Comment: I'm not getting it corrected with this, but thank you tough for the answer.

Comment: I get the divs moved when trying to write on it. For example in DIV 1. Why is that? TY.

Comment: @Jim I edited it again with the new jsfiddle, you need to import a reset.css in order to have less  inconsistencies

Comment: In the new jsfiddle the div's are also moved. It is because of the browser? I'll learn about reset.css if it solves this problem. Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

I have tried something like your picture.

## CSS

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#content {
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#content > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
.tophcontent {
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
.midhcontent {
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: calc(100% - 46px);
  border: 2px solid green;
}
#leftinfo {
  border: 3px solid gray;
  width:120px;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="leftinfo">
        <ul>
            <li>INFO</li>
            <li>ABOUT</li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div id="header">
        <div class="tophcontent">
        </div>
        <div class="midhcontent">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/us2mhL9v/4/)

Comment: That doesn't allow me to add content to ".tophcontent" and ".midhcontent" while the divs move on chaotically. Any idea on how to correct that?

Comment: @Jim Everything is fine https://jsfiddle.net/us2mhL9v/7/, but I have set the height of ".tophcontent" to `40px` therefore the text vertically overflow out of `DIV`.

Answer (score 1):

Is it something like this you mean ?

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/o0nico0o/pen/jqppdq)

```
body, html{
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width: 90%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.left{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
    background:green;
}

.top-right{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    left:31%;
    height:30%;
    float:left;
    background:blue;
}

.bottom-right{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    left:31%;
    bottom:0;
    top:32%;
    float:left;
    background:red;
}
```